# Create EKEvent with no alarm

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, eventkit

I'm creating an EKEvent attached to a custom calendar. Whenever I create the EKEvent an alarm is set for the time of the event, however, I would like this event to not have an alarm on creation.

I've tried setting the event's alarms property to...

```
event.alarms = nil
```

as well as...

```
event.alarms = []
```

I've also tried setting the alarm to a distant future data, but this just adds another alarm to the event...

```
event.alarms = [Date.distantFuture]
```

I've done all this before saving the event, but it has given me no results, the alarm fires no matter what I do. :(

Here is the code I'm using to create the calendar:

```
let calendar = EKCalendar(for: .event, eventStore: store)
var source = store.sources.filter{ $0.sourceType == .calDAV && $0.title == "iCloud" }.first
if source == nil {
    source = store.sources.filter{ $0.sourceType == .local }.first
}
calendar!.title = "Some Title"
calendar!.cgColor = ColorKey.orange.color().cgColor
calendar!.source = source!

do {
    try store.saveCalendar(calendar!, commit: true)
} catch {
    //error handling here...
}
```

And this is the code that I'm using to create the event:

```
let event = EKEvent(eventStore: store)
event.title = "Some title"
event.notes = "Some notes"
event.startDate = dateToFire
event.endDate = dateToFire.addingTimeInterval(TimeInSeconds.hour.rawValue)
event.isAllDay = false
event.calendar = calendar
do {
    try store.save(event, span: EKSpan.futureEvents)
} catch {
    //error handling here...
}
```

Is this a bug on the OS or am I missing something?
Thanks!

Comment: Danny, I was just about to post an identical question.  In addition to removing alarms (despite there being no alarm to remove), I've tried saving the `eventIdentifier` when I create the event, and (much later) going back and fetching that same event.  There are still no alarms to remove.  I can manually remove the alarm using the Calendar app (by setting the alert to "None").  But, how to do it programmatically when creating and saving the event?  If you have not solved this problem, we can try to get attention by setting bounties.

Comment: I have found and posted the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the removealaram method from the EkCalendarItem class?

Comment: I tried removing the alarm after saving the event to the store but the calendar notification still came through.

Answer (score 0):

There are default alert settings in Apple's Calendar app.  Launch Calendar, then go to Preferences, Alerts.  There are three settings there (Events, All Day Events, Birthdays). Set them to "None."  (I'm using macOS 10.14, Calendar 11.0.)